# How do I get a reference to a Win7 library from a common controls dialog hook?

Tags: c++, windows-7, common-controls

I am implementing an [`OFNHookProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646931(VS.85).aspx) to instrument a common controls [`GetOpenFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927(VS.85).aspx) dialog on Windows 7.  My instrumentation is written in C++.  Things work fine until the user selects a Library (like Documents or Pictures).  When this happens, I get the `CDN_FOLDERCHANGE` notification like I expect, but when I send the dialog the `CDM_GETFOLDERPATH` message to retrieve the newly selected folder, I get an error return of -1, with `CommDlgExtendedError` returning 0.  In some ways, this makes sense, since it's not a folder, but none of the other messages seem to work either (like `CDM_GETFOLDERIDLIST` or `CDM_GETFILEPATH`).

So, how do you tell from an `OFNHookProc` that the currently selected item or folder is a library?  Once you can tell that it's a library, how do you get an `IShellItem` or `IShellLibrary` interface to it such that you can figure out what file system folders constitute the library?

(The code that creates the `GetOpenFileName` dialog is legacy code, so I can't replace it with the Windows-7-recommended `IFileOpenDialog` interface that supports Libraries in a sane manner).